# React: Ways of passing component as a props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

What is difference between these two way of passing component as props.

1. Passing `RepoMenu` as it is:

```
<Fetch
  url={`https://api.github.com/users/${login}/repos`}
  renderSuccess={RepoMenu}
/>
```

2. Wrapping the `RepoMenu` in a function

```
<Fetch
  url={`https://api.github.com/users/${login}/repos`}
  renderSuccess={({ data }) => <RepoMenu data={data} />}
/>
```

`RepoMenu` internally uses a custom hook.

```
function RepoMenu({ data, onSelect = (f) => f }) {
  const [{ name }, prev, next] = useIterator(data);

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <button onClick={prev}>&lt;</button>
      <p>{name}</p>
      <button onClick={next}>&gt;</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Using one (Passing RepoMenu as it is) starts failing, React starts throwing an exception `Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.`

Initially i thought may it is not possible to use the component like the method `1`. But to test it more further i created a small Pure Component and just tried to render the data passed to it.

```
function RepoMenuPure({ data = [], onSelect = (f) => f }) {
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <h3>There are {data.length} repos for this user</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And when i tried to use it like below, It worked in this case.

```
const UserRepositories = ({ login, selectedRepo, onSelect = (f) => f }) => {
  return (
    <Fetch
      url={`https://api.github.com/users/${login}/repos`}
      renderSuccess={RepoMenuPure}
    />
  );
};
```

Can someone please help me explain what is happening and what i am missing?

I have created a small sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-example-bqfn3e?file=/src/App.js

Comment: FYI, whenever you write `<Foo><Bar /></Foo>`, `<Bar />` is passed as a component to the `children` props of `<Foo>` component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return renderSuccess({ data });
```

Your problem is you're calling a component like a function. Every time you call `renderSuccess` (which is `RepoMenu` - now it's not considered a component), it will trigger your custom hook `useIterator` which is invalid.

You can refer to [this document](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.

*Nested functions* part is your current situation.

With the pure component, it was working because you didn't use any hooks, that's why you don't see any errors come out.

For the fix, you can do it this way

```
import React from "react";
import { useFetch } from "./hooks/useFetch";

function Fetch({
  url,
  loadingFallback = <div>Loading....</div>,
  errorFallback = <div>Some thing went wrong</div>,
  renderSuccess: RenderSuccess //introduce it as a component
}) {
  const { data, error, loading } = useFetch(url);

  if (loading) {
    return loadingFallback;
  }

  if (error) {
    return errorFallback;
  }

  if (data) {
    return <RenderSuccess data={data} />; //render a component instead of executing a function
  }

  return null;
}

export default Fetch;
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-example-forked-hctqfe?file=/src/Fetch.js:0-477)

Comment: Thanks @Nick, this was the key, I am "calling a component like a function", Thanks for your time.

Comment: You're welcome!~ @RaviOjha. If you think the answer is useful, please help us to mark it as a solution, that would be giving a little support to us as well as our community :D

Comment: Ahh, i thought i did already :). I Accepted this now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the first option :

```js
renderSuccess={({ data }) => <RepoMenu data={data} />}
```

You are saying that `Fetch` component expects that `renderSuccess` receives a function that returns a `Component`. If you were using typescript, the type of `renderSuccess` in `Fetch`  would be something like:

```js
renderSuccess : (data: any) => JSX.Element

// OR return the component itself
renderSuccess : (data: any) => RepoMenu
```

And that´s why when you call `renderSuccess({ data })` inside `Fetch` component works.

In the second option:

```js
renderSuccess={RepoMenu}
```

You are saying that `Fetch` component expects that `renderSuccess` receives the  `RepoMenu` Component (not a function). If you were using typescript, the type of `renderSuccess` in `Fetch`  would be something like:

```js
renderSuccess : JSX.Element

// OR the component itself
renderSuccess : RepoMenu
```

For this option work, you should change your Fetch component to something like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useFetch } from "./hooks/useFetch";

function Fetch({
  url,
  loadingFallback = <div>Loading....</div>,
  errorFallback = <div>Some thing went wrong</div>,
  renderSuccess: Component
  //renderSuccess
}) {
  // console.log("renderSuccess", renderSuccess);

  const { data, error, loading } = useFetch(url);

  if (loading) {
    return loadingFallback;
  }

  if (error) {
    return errorFallback;
  }

  if (data) {
    // return renderSuccess({ data });
    return <Component data={data} />;
  }

  return null;
}

export default Fetch;
```

Comment: Thanks @Luis, very nicely explained. Thanks for your time.